# What font style does Journal of Finance use?

Tags: fonts

I know that using

```
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

gets quite close to the Journal of Finance font, but still it is not equivalent. The JOF style is much rounder and the letters seem bigger.

Doen anybody know which package resembles JOF the most?

Comment: I think it's [New Century Schoolbook](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newcent/).

Answer (score 0):

Downloading http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2012.01793.x/asset/j.1540-6261.2012.01793.x.pdf?v=1&t=hiowgl9j&s=616f242a1fdb28f23b23eafcc9d8ae2623a2f274 lets one examine the .pdf using standard techniques which reveals that it was made w/ LaTeX using the hyperref package and uses the fonts:

- New Century Schoolbook
- Times New Roman PS
- Symbol and various other TeX math fonts

For some reason, the masthead is a bitmap image, it looks like it uses Bulmer and Bulmer Italic.